# TensorFlow image recognition output format c++

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I use tensorflow for image recognition from [main.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc), with the command:

> bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image

The current output format in terminal is:

> 2017-04-19: I tensorflow/.../main.cc:206] military uniform (653): 0.834307
>
> 2017-04-19: I tensorflow/.../main.cc:206] mortarboard (668): 0.0218693
>
> 2017-04-19: I tensorflow/.../main.cc:206] academic gown (401): 0.010358
>
> 2017-04-19: I tensorflow/.../main.cc:206] pickelhaube (716): 0.00800809
>
> 2017-04-19: I tensorflow/.../main.cc:206] bulletproof vest (466): 0.00535086

Output function is:

```
// this prints out the top five highest-scoring values.
Status PrintTopLabels(const std::vector<Tensor>& outputs,
                      string labels_file_name) {
  std::vector<string> labels;
  size_t label_count;
  Status read_labels_status =
      ReadLabelsFile(labels_file_name, &labels, &label_count);
  if (!read_labels_status.ok()) {
    LOG(ERROR) << read_labels_status;
    return read_labels_status;
  }
  const int how_many_labels = std::min(5, static_cast<int>(label_count));
  Tensor indices;
  Tensor scores;
  TF_RETURN_IF_ERROR(GetTopLabels(outputs, how_many_labels, &indices, &scores));
  tensorflow::TTypes<float>::Flat scores_flat = scores.flat<float>();
  tensorflow::TTypes<int32>::Flat indices_flat = indices.flat<int32>();
  for (int pos = 0; pos < how_many_labels; ++pos) {
    const int label_index = indices_flat(pos);
    const float score = scores_flat(pos);
    LOG(INFO) << labels[label_index] << " (" << label_index << "): " << score;
  }
  return Status::OK();
}
```

Problem is, I want the output to be a list like:

> military uniform, mortarboard, academic gown, pickelhaube, bulletproof vest

It is possible to have such an output?

Comment: do you have any trouble execute this command?: bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image/...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, I think it is possible. Replace:

```
LOG(INFO) << labels[label_index] << " (" << label_index << "): " << score;
```

with

```
std::cout << label[label_index] << ",";
```

okay now there is a comma more than we need. So we check before if it is the last concept and in case it is we leave the comma away.

I hope that helps.